# Homebrew: how to remove redis/4.0.2 and use redis@3.2 as my default redis

Tags: redis, homebrew

I started this quest with redis/3.0.3 installed, and looking to upgrade my local dev redis to version 3.2.3, which is what we're running in production. I ultimately ran `brew upgrade redis`, which installed redis 4.0.2, ahead of my desired version. Then I found that you can install 3.2.x with `brew install redis@3.2`. Also, while trying to cleanup 4.0.2, instead it cleaned up only 3.0.3.

Now I'm stuck in a situation where Homebrew won't allow me to uninstall redis/4.0.2, and views redis@3.2 as a separate Homebrew Formula.

```
$ brew switch redis 3.2
Error: redis does not have a version "3.2" in the Cellar.
Versions available: 4.0.2
```

See how in the Cellar, they're showing as separate Formulae here:

```
$ ls  /usr/local/Cellar/ | grep redis  
redis
redis@3.2
```

***What is the correct "Homebrew" way to remove redis/4.0.2 and use redis@3.2 as my default redis, so that commands to `redis-server` and `redis-cli` reference 3.2 instead?*** I'm running Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 and Homebrew 1.3.4.

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/ | grep redis
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jsoro  wheel        41 Oct  5 12:51 redis-benchmark -> ../Cellar/redis/4.0.2/bin/redis-benchmark
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jsoro  wheel        41 Oct  5 12:51 redis-check-aof -> ../Cellar/redis/4.0.2/bin/redis-check-aof
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jsoro  wheel        41 Oct  5 12:51 redis-check-rdb -> ../Cellar/redis/4.0.2/bin/redis-check-rdb
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jsoro  wheel        35 Oct  5 12:51 redis-cli -> ../Cellar/redis/4.0.2/bin/redis-cli
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jsoro  wheel        40 Oct  5 12:51 redis-sentinel -> ../Cellar/redis/4.0.2/bin/redis-sentinel
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jsoro  wheel        38 Oct  5 12:51 redis-server -> ../Cellar/redis/4.0.2/bin/redis-server
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue was trivial and could have been easier if the Brew Docs/FAQs were more clear. The [Brew FAQs](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ.html) say that uninstalls are handled by `brew cleanup <formula>`, which is what caused my redis/3.0.3 to be removed. However, `brew cleanup` would not remove redis/4.0.2. To remove it I used `brew uninstall`, which I could not find in the Docs...

```
$ brew uninstall redis
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/redis/4.0.2... (11 files, 2.7MB)
```

Then, to fix the remaining issue of redis@3.2 not being symlinked under `/usr/local/bin/`, I first tried an uninstall/re-install of redis@3.2 to see if Homebrew would take care of it...

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/ | grep redis
$ brew uninstall redis@3.2
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/redis@3.2/3.2.11... (11 files, 1.7MB)
$ brew install redis@3.2
==> Downloading http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-3.2.11.tar.gz
## TRIMMED ##
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/redis@3.2/3.2.11: 11 files, 1.7MB, built in 10 seconds
```

Of course, this did not create the symlinks--actually the Caveats section which I trimmed away from the output says this explicitly with suggestions. Instead of using their suggestion, I opted to create symlinks manually:

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin/
$ ls -l | grep redis
$
$ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/redis\@3.2/3.2.11/bin/redis-check-aof redis-check-aof
$ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/redis\@3.2/3.2.11/bin/redis-check-rdb redis-check-rdb
$ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/redis\@3.2/3.2.11/bin/redis-cli redis-cli
$ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/redis\@3.2/3.2.11/bin/redis-sentinel redis-sentinel
$ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/redis\@3.2/3.2.11/bin/redis-server redis-server
$ ls -l | grep redis
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jsoro  wheel        54 Oct  5 14:27 redis-check-aof -> /usr/local/Cellar/redis@3.2/3.2.11/bin/redis-check-aof
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jsoro  wheel        54 Oct  5 14:27 redis-check-rdb -> /usr/local/Cellar/redis@3.2/3.2.11/bin/redis-check-rdb
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jsoro  wheel        48 Oct  5 14:27 redis-cli -> /usr/local/Cellar/redis@3.2/3.2.11/bin/redis-cli
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jsoro  wheel        53 Oct  5 14:27 redis-sentinel -> /usr/local/Cellar/redis@3.2/3.2.11/bin/redis-sentinel
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jsoro  wheel        51 Oct  5 14:26 redis-server -> /usr/local/Cellar/redis@3.2/3.2.11/bin/redis-server
```

The last thing to note is that since I had run the redis-server while under the redis/4.0.2 version, the dump.rdb file was no longer compatible. Running  `redis-server` using redis 3.2.x on a 4.x dump.rdb causes the server to exit immediately.

```
$ redis-server
## TRIMMED ##
38504:M 05 Oct 14:29:07.234 # Server started, Redis version 3.2.11
38504:M 05 Oct 14:29:07.259 # Can't handle RDB format version 8
38504:M 05 Oct 14:29:07.260 # Fatal error loading the DB: Invalid argument. Exiting.
```

Unfortunately you need to `rm dump.rdb`, or remove/rename the dump.rdb file, in order to get redis-server to start up again.

Comment: The FAQ say `brew cleanup` is used to remove *old versions* of formulae; not that it’s used to remove any formula. That task is already handled by `brew uninstall`, which is mentioned on the page you linked, just under "How do I uninstall a formula?".

Comment: Not precisely. The FAQs only mention uninstall with the force flag, and explicitly warn that it's "destructive" so as to dissuade use. Also, since the mention isn't in code blocks it's relatively invisible on the page.

Comment: That’s true. Unless you want to do it, I’ll make a PR to propose a better wording/formatting.

Comment: Good idea :) Thank you for submitting the PR

Comment: I did this and then just added the redis bin folder to my path, that way I didn't have to symlink everything into another bin folder.